# Set of negligible functions $\phi$ with $Im(\phi) \subseteq N$. What does it mean?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

I am solving the following problem. If I have a subset $G$ of negligible functions defined as $G=\{\phi$ is a negligible function where $Im(\phi)\subseteq \mathbb{N}\}$, and defined $(G,\circ)$. I have to show, if $(G,\circ)$ is semigroup, monoid, group or Abelian group.
I don't understand what does Im($\phi)\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ mean, it is a function $\phi(x):\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \{0,1\}$?

Thank you for any help...

Comment: What is $N$? Do the elements of $G$ have a common (co)domain?

Comment: As for what $\operatorname{Im}(\phi)\subseteq N$ means, it means that $\phi(x)\in N$ for all $x$ in the domain of $\phi.$

Comment: What's the definition of "negligible function"?  Your statement is a bit unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm correct, a *negligible function* is a function $\mu:\Bbb N\to\Bbb R$ such that for each positive integer $k$ there is a positive integer $N_k$ such that $$|\mu(n)|<\frac1{n^k}$$ whenever $n>N_k$. In particular, then, $$G=\{\phi:\Bbb N\to\Bbb N\mid\phi\text{ is negligible}\}.$$

The answer to your question depends heavily on whether or not $0\in\Bbb N$ for you (some definitions have $\Bbb N$ as the positive integers, some as the nonnegative integers).

In the case that $0\notin\Bbb N,$ then $G=\varnothing$ (why?), so I suspect that by your definition, we have $0\in\Bbb N.$ Then by definition of negligibility, it follows that $$G=\{\phi:\Bbb N\to\Bbb N\mid\exists N\in\Bbb N\text{ such that }\phi(n)=0\text{ for }n\ge N\}.$$ Do you see why this is true?

---

The relevant definitions of the algebraic structure types in question are as follows.

> $\langle G,\circ\rangle$ is a *semigroup* if and only if the following hold:
>
> - $\forall \phi,\psi\in G,$ we have $\phi\circ\psi\in G.$
> - $\forall \phi,\psi,\chi\in G,$ we have $\phi\circ(\psi\circ\chi)=(\phi\circ\psi)\circ\chi.$
>
> $\langle G,\circ,\rangle$ is a *monoid* if and only if the following hold:
>
> - $\langle G,\circ\rangle$ is a semigroup.
> - $\exists\varepsilon\in G$ such that $\forall\phi\in G,$ we have $\phi\circ\varepsilon=\varepsilon\circ\phi=\phi.$
>
> $\langle G,\circ\rangle$ is a *group* if and only if the following hold:
>
> - $\langle G,\circ\rangle$ is a monoid.
> - $\forall \phi\in G$ $\exists\psi\in G$ such that $\phi\circ\psi=\psi\circ\phi=\varepsilon. (Where $\varepsilon$ is as described in the definition of monoid.)
>
> $\langle G,\circ\rangle$ is an *abelian group* if and only if the following hold:
>
> - $\langle G,\circ\rangle$ is a group.
> - $\forall \phi,\psi\in G,$ we have $\phi\circ\psi=\psi\circ\phi.$

Observe that: if $\langle G,\circ\rangle$ is not a semigroup, then it is not a monoid or a(n abelian) group; if $\langle G,\circ\rangle$ is not a monoid, then it is not a(n abelian group); if $\langle G,\circ\rangle$ is not a group, then it is not an abelian group.

---

I will tell you this: $\langle G,\circ\rangle$ is *not* an abelian group. Your task, then, is to find the most general algebraic structure type that $\langle G,\circ\rangle$ *fails* to be. It will then follow (by our observation above) that $\langle G,\circ\rangle$ cannot be any of the more specific algebraic structure types, either, but that $\langle G,\circ\rangle$ is of each of the more general structure types (if there are any such). Work your way from most general to most specific, and let me know if you have any trouble.

Comment: Thank you very much for answer. I can't decide if it holds that $\phi\circ\psi\in G.$. If $\psi(n)=0$ is $\phi(0) \in G$? Contains the codomain only $\{0\}$?

Comment: The codomain is $\Bbb N$.

Comment: If  $\mu:\Bbb N\to\Bbb R$ and $|\mu(n)|<\frac1{n^k}$ then on the right side I get only values smaller than one...Therefore the image of $\mu(n)$ should be only zero, or am I wrong?

Comment: It isn't necessary to have $$|\mu(n)|<\frac1{n^k}\tag{1}$$ for *all* $n\in\Bbb N$ (that would be impossible, since $0\in\Bbb N$). All that is necessary is that $(1)$ is satisfied for *large enough* $n.$ For example, let $\mu(0)=\mu(1)=\mu(2)=...=\mu(1000)=5000000$ and let $\mu(n)=0$ for $n>1000.$ Then $\mu\in G,$ since $\mu:\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$ and for each positive integer $k,$ putting $N_k=1000,$ we have that $(1)$ holds for $n>N_k.$

Comment: I strongly advise you to prove that $$G=\{\phi:\Bbb N\to\Bbb N\mid\exists N\in\Bbb N\text{ such that }\phi(n)=0\text{ for }n\ge N\},$$ before you try to determine which (if any) algebraic structure properties $\langle G,\circ\rangle$ has. That definition of $G$ will make your life a great deal easier.

Comment: Thanks for patience :). So I suppose that $\phi\circ\psi\in G$ holds. Also the asociativity of composition of correctly defined functions from $G$. However it is not a monoid, because the only one neutral function can be $\varepsilon(x)=x$ but $\varepsilon(x) \notin G$ because it is strictly increasing function

Comment: Indeed, it is not a monoid (so not a group, or an abelian group), and that's precisely why! It's also true that composition of functions in general is associative when the domains and codomains are compatible. Why is it that $\phi\circ\psi\in G$ whenever $\phi,\psi\in G$?

Comment: Is it possible that I was wrong. There can be function defined as: $\phi(x) = x+1$ if $x < 1000$, $0$ otherwise. $\phi$ is in $G$ however $\phi\circ\phi\notin G$ because I never get as  result number $0$ from $\phi(\phi(x)), x \in \Bbb N$..oops, sorry..It is actually possible for $x=999$...

Comment: You've got something of the right idea. Here's a hint that will hopefully get you the rest of the way: let $\psi(n)=0$ for all $n$ (so clearly $\psi\in G$) and see if you can find some $\phi\in G$ such that $\phi\circ\psi\notin G$.

Comment: The correct definition of $\phi$ can be $\phi(x)=x$ if $x<1000 \wedge x\neq0$, $1$ if $x=0$, $0$ otherwise..

Comment: That works just fine, yes, since then $(\phi\circ\psi)(n)=1$ for all $n\in\Bbb N.$ Actually, any $\phi\in G$ such that $\phi(0)\ne 0$ will do the trick. And there you go! $\langle G,\circ\rangle$ isn't even a semigroup!

Comment: Do you have any other questions about my answer or this problem? If not, then you can "accept" my answer by clicking the check mark in my answer. This gives reputation points to you and to me, and signals to the other users that the question has been satisfactorily resolved. (You can also "upvote" if you like, and if you haven't already.)